# Update from table to another WHERE t1.substring=t2.col

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update, substring

I need to **update Table 1** from Table 2 **where the substring of a T1.column** will match a **T2.column in Table2**

No luck with the below code, getting error on line 4 onwards:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET
NAME = T2.NAME,
AGE = T2.AGE
FROM TABLE2 T2
WHERE SUBSTRING(REFERENCE,1,2)=T2.REF_ID
```

| T1.REFERENCE | T1.NAME | T1.AGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00ABC |  |  |
| 01XXX |  |  |

| T2.REF_ID | T2.NAME | T2.AGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | ELON | 18 |
| 01 | MUSK | 30 |

Comment: If you're using MySQL why tag [tag:sql-server]? I have removed the tag, I assume it was in error. As for your question, you say you get an error, however, what *is* that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax would work in Postgresql, but in MySql you need a join:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 t1 
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
ON LEFT(t1.REFERENCE, 2) = t2.REF_ID 
SET t1.NAME = t2.NAME,
    t1.AGE = t2.AGE
```